# Formating Text within a UITextView using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to add an "About" View into my (swift) iOS App. Currently I have centered a UiTextView into this ViewController. Now I am wondering if it's possible to format text in this TextView like I can for instance in a html website?

Or is it better to use some other component for this?

Thanks

Comment: `NSAttributedString`? What "format" are you looking for?

Comment: TextView + AttributedString is the most flexible way. But if you are not accustomed with it and are in a hurry ... go the old way: UIWebView and manually load the html from a file in your bundle. Most of the time you'll lose quality an flexibility though.

Comment: I guess I will go with a plain html way. Other things seems to be to 
complicated. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not supposed to be editable (it's an about page), why not go with a UILabel?

You can use NSAttributedString to get access to more customization options than what you get with NSString.